# AJAX File Upload passing ID

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins

I am using this AJAX File Upload plugin:

http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/

I made this function that will loop through all file inputs

```
function ajaxFileUpload() {
        $('input[type=file]').each(function() {
            $.ajaxFileUpload ({
                url:'upload.inc.php',
                secureuri:false,
                fileElementId:this.id,
                dataType: 'json'
            })
        });
        return false;
```

The problem is, I am uploading files to two different folders. All file inputs have 'name="image"' on them. So I need to create a conditional statement to tell the program what folder I should put them in. But in order for me to do this, I need to get the class the file input so I can create something like this:

```
switch(fileInputClass) {
case 'mainImage':
//upload to folder 1
break;
case 'subImage':
//upload to folder 2
}
```

So how can I pass the class string to my 'upload.inc.php' so that I can conditionally tell what folder it should be uploaded to? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass it as a querystring parameter along with the url.

Try something like this

```
 function ajaxFileUpload() {
    $('input[type=file]').each(function() {
        $.ajaxFileUpload ({
            url: getUploadUrl(this.className),
            secureuri:false,
            fileElementId:this.id,
            dataType: 'json'
        })
    });
    return false;
 }

 function getUploadUrl(class){
     switch(class) {
         case 'mainImage':
              return 'upload.inc.php?uploadfolder=folder1'
         case 'subImage':
              return 'upload.inc.php?uploadfolder=folder2'
      }
 }
```

On the server side get the querystring value using `$_GET['uploadfolder']`